# How to find gaps of more than 7 days in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with tons of logs on it timestamped every minute and second they occur. I have trying to find gaps where a certain set of logs does not have events for stretches of more than 7 days. So if there are no events for more than a 7 day period let me know what location. Any ideas on how to do that?

Update:
Based on the suggestion below I am trying this but it just runs and runs and never finishes.

```
SELECT controller
  FROM [events].[dbo].[Event_View] t
  Where (t.timestamp > '2020-08-01 00:00' and t.timestamp < '2020-09-01 00:00') and not exists 
(Select 1 from [events].[dbo].[Event_View] tt
  Where controller = tt.controller
    And tt.timestamp between t.timestamp and dateadd(day, -7, t.timestamp)
);
```

Comment: Lets start by adding some sample data to your question.

Comment: Have a look at LAG() and LEAD() window functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` or `lead()`, like this:

```
select ev.*
from (select ev.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by controller order by timestamp) as prev_ts
      from [events].[dbo].[Event_View] ev
     ) ev
where prev_ts < dateadd(day, -7, timestamp);
```

Comment: What would be the partition order by missing part based on my example in my original post?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
Select t.* from your_table t
Where not exists 
(Select 1 from your_table tt
  Where t.log_type = tt.log_type
    And tt.day_column between t.day_column and dateadd(day, -7, t.day_column)
    And t.pk_col <> tt.pk_col);
```

Comment: I am trying this but it is just running and running and never finishing with results. I updated my post to show what I am doing.